# Perform aws alb healthcheck on wsgi:// server

Tags: uwsgi, wsgi, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a wsgi server running at uwsgi://mydomain.com behind an AWS application load balancer.

If I set protocol=http in uwsgi, then it works fine. However, I would like to keep the uwsgi protocol to interface with my nginx server (as opposed to doing a proxy_pass). There is no option in the ALB console to do a custom protocol check.

Is there some kind of workaround I can do to use ALB for healthchecking an app under the uwsgi:// protocol?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I suspect you need nginx to do the translation of http to uwsgi for you.